# How to show one picture slide in largest possible size after showing each item in the provided Beamer TeX?

Tags: beamer, overlays, presentations

I have 3 figures and 3 items. After each item is shown, I would like to show one figure at the largest size that may be fitted on a Beamer class slide.

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}


\usetheme{Darmstadt}        


\begin{document}

\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}

\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
  \item First Item
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{First Figure}
        \end{minipage}
  \item Second Item 
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{Second Figure}
        \end{minipage}
  \item Third Item
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
     \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{Third Figure}
        \end{minipage}


\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As for your question, do you (1) want to have a hyperlink jumping to an extra slide that only shows the picture or (2) draw the picture as large as possible in the rest of the slide?

Comment: @marmot I want each picture to be shown by a click and as large as possible in a slide merely showing that picture. So I guess it is number (1).

Comment: Can you draw a sketch how the layout should look like? I find it unclear what you mean by largest possible size. Below the item? The whole text area? The whole paper?

Comment: @user157323 When you include images, specify either the width or the height, but not both at the same time as this will distort your images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope to understand your question correctly. If you click on the image, it will bring you to a slide which you may put at the very end of your presentation. If you click on the image there you'll jump back. Other options include `\framezoom`.

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}        


\begin{document}

\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\label{frm:Outline}

\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
  \item First Item
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
    \hyperlink{frm:first_image}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
        \end{minipage}
  \item Second Item 
   \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
   \hyperlink{frm:second_image}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}}
        \end{minipage}
  \item Third Item
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering

\hyperlink{frm:third_image}{\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}}
        \end{minipage}


\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:first_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-a}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:second_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image-b}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\label{frm:third_image}
     \centering
\hyperlink{frm:Outline}{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}
}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Or you can use `\pause` and `\only`.

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\begin{document}

\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\label{frm:Outline}

\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
  \item First Item
\only<1>{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{minipage}
        }
\pause      
  \item Second Item 
\only<2>{\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
   \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-b}
        \end{minipage}
  }     
\pause  
  \item Third Item
\only<3>{ \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
     \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image-c}
        \end{minipage}
}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this is how I would probably do it.

```
\documentclass[
    aspectratio=169
]{beamer}

\usetheme{Darmstadt}        

\begin{document}

\section{Outline}
\subsection{Outline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\label{frm:Outline}

\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{4cm}
\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{1.5\baselineskip}
  \item<1-> First Item
  \item<2-> Second Item 
  \item<3-> Third Item
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{8cm}
     \centering
\only<1>{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=7cm]{example-image-a}}
\pause
\only<2>{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=7cm]{example-image-b}}
\pause
\only<3>{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=7cm]{example-image-c}}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I was not clear enough. I want each picture simple as one slide, and not through a hyperlink--and by clicking I just meant pressing just a button (e.g. Space or Enter). I think that is what is called overlaying.

Comment: @user157323 But if you do not click on the picture, how would beamer know which picture it should zoom?

Comment: Isn't it possible just by the way of the name of picture? The same way we show items one after another, I want to show pictures one after another, actually first item1 then picture1, then item2 then picture2, ... .

Comment: @user157323 I added another version. Is that closer to what you want? Is your question how to make the picture as large as possible given the remaining space?

Comment: I think the best way for me is to go with hyperlink. But I don't want the pictures in the pager where items are. Also, I want to go to each picture just by tabbing a button and coming back again just by tabbing a button. so it is like this: Item1, then I tab the button and picture1 comes, then I tap the button and I will be back to items slide with item1 and item2 in it, then I tab again and go to picture2, then I tab and come back to items slide with item1 and item2 and item3 in it, and so on